# Classic ASP Twitter Libraries

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, twitter

Does of anyone know of any Classic ASP (VBScript) Twitter libraries? Thanks.

Comment: people are still using classic ASP? zomg

Comment: I am still using it for some projects because i have already application legacy written in VBScript

Answer (score 3):

http://scottdesapio.com/VBScriptOAuth/

Not a twitter library but rather a true VBScript OAuth interface. That help?

Answer (score 0):

Made one in VbScript as well http://sitejunction.awardspace.com/vbscript_tweets/

Answer (score -1):

I write my own Twitter API implementation with VBScript,
http://asp.web.id/asp-twitter

it is currently support

- user show
- user timeline
- friends timeline
- statuses mentions
- statuses update

and i am intend to add more implementation of api methods especially for twitter search

Answer (score -2):

Please have a look at the following:

http://code.google.com/p/twitter-oauth-in-classic-asp/
http://groups.google.com/group/twitter-oauth-in-classic-asp

Comment: -1 it says nothing, no method is implementing ASP: "Functions that need to be modified have the original PHP script still embedded." in other words: ALL Methods !

Comment: Thanks for wasting my time. No usable code whatsoever.